Is it allowed to use names taken from popular culture in source code?
I'm talking about the names of characters, locations, etc.taken from movies, video games, etc. when used as names of functions/variables, arrays of strings, etc. Would using a large amount of these names in source code infringe the intellectual property of the owners? Or it's allowed because it's just like using these names in a wiki or encyclopedia?

Can you be a little more specific? "pop culture" is not a legal term. Do you mean copyrighted works? Trademarked terms? Is someone under an NDA?

What exactly do you mean by using them in source code.

Whether it's legal or not, for reasons of clarity just don't: use names that describe the function/variable's use/purpose!

@TripeHound Maybe OP wants to write obfuscated code?

Names of characters in pop culture are usually protected as trademarks.
For the purposes of trademark, "using" a mark generally means in contexts where the public will see or hear it, with the potential to believe that it's related to the trademark holder. In the case of software, this would generally be the user interface of the program, programming packaging, and marketing material.
While the source code of an open source program is available to the public, I don't think it would be considered a use in trade. But IANAL, and I don't know if there's any precedent that would apply.
